# UPDATE a value field for area of the geom and convert sq m to acres using cartodb

Tags: postgresql, carto, sql, area, update

I'm trying to use the SQL commands in CartoDB to UPDATE a value field that shows total acres of the area of the_geom. My SQL is pretty poor/entry level and has some issues:

```
UPDATE table_name SET shape_area=(SELECT ST_Area(the_geom::geography) area_sqm 
FROM table_name)
```

I'm missing something... any help?

Comment: The thing you appear to be missing, is the conversion from m^2 to acres. I am guessing that shape_area should be in acres and the_geom is in meters, therefore you need to apply a factor of 0.000247105381 to you ST_Area call to get acres. Otherwise, I see nothing wrong other than the curious addiction that the world's most technically sophisticated county seems to have for the imperial system :D.

Comment: @JohnBarça zang!

Comment: Thanks, John! One follow on question that this brings me to- Any idea why it winds up returning the error message "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"?

Comment: @mapBaker, zing. Sorry, couldn't resist that. I recall the story about the rocket that malfunctioned because NASA was working in feet and the contractor in meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running an update, there is no need for a subquery with a SELECT. This is the cause of the

> more than one row returned by subquery used as an expression

error, as the SELECT will return multiple rows.

Instead, you want:

```
UPDATE table_name SET shape_area = ST_Area(the_geom::geography)*0.00024711;
```

which will update your table on a row by row basis, fill in the field, `shape_area`, with the acre equivalent, assuming that your geometry column, the_geom, has units of meters.

Comment: My apologies for missing that before -- the imperial system seems to fry my brain. I grew up at that time in the UK when everything was going metric.

Comment: Amazing! this did the trick exceptionally well!   ---- And as a quick ode to metric - I spent 4 years in Canada so there's a soft spot in my heart for metric as well. particularly when it comes to temps. I still think in Centigrade more than Fahrenheit ..

Comment: I lived in New York for a while. Took me ages to adjust to 25 being freezing. That's beach weather here :-) Glad you are enjoying CartoDB/Postgis. Great software.